# Windows Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, windows-xp, windows-registry

I made a critical change to my system which ruined my windows environment. I later knew it can be resolved by System Restore. When I was about to run it this message prompted me.

> System Restore has been turned off by group policy. To turn on System Restore, contact your domain Administrator.

I have researched about group policy on Windows XP Professional SP3, yet can't find where to get the system restore running. Where in the `gpedit.msc` will I find a solution to this matter?

Answer (score 0):

The setting is under Group Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> System Restore.

By default System Restore is enabled. If your computer in domain, run rsop.msc to figure out how this setting gets configured. If it was set by your domain policies you won't be able to override it. At least not at easy.

Answer (score 0):

GPEdit may not help if your setting is defined in Domain Policy.

If you need to turn off the setting, you can run regedit and delete the following registry value which is essentially the "policy":

```
    Key: HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\SystemRestore
    Value: DisableSR
```

Note that every time you restart and by default every 90 minutes group policy is reapplied, so you may need to be creative on how this is overridden.